# K3 surface with $D_{14}$ singular fiber

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, k3-surfaces, elliptic-surfaces

Let $X$ be an elliptic K3 surface with $D_{14}$ singular fiber. Do you know an explicit equation for such $X$? Also, how many disjoint sections such fibration admits? Any reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you give some motivation? I suppose you mean $\tilde{D}_{14} $. Do you know that such fibration exists? Is it maximal in some sense?

Comment: Sometimes the same singularity is denoted as ${I^{*}}_{19}$. Yes, such fibration exists according to some literature. It has the maximal singular fibers.

Comment: I meant ${I^{*}}_{14}$.

Comment: In what sense is it maximal? I can easily think of $\tilde D_{16}+\tilde A_2+3\tilde A_0$, and that one would indeed be extremal.

Comment: "the maximal singular fibers" means the number of components are maximal. Alex: could you please give the description (or reference) of fibration on $K3$ with $\tilde{D_{16}}$ singular fiber. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[In comments **guest2014** amended the question to ask not for a
$D_{14}$ fiber but for $I^*_{14}$, a.k.a. $\tilde D_{18}$]

The elliptic surface 
$$
X : y^2 = x^3 + (t^3+2t) x^2 - 2(t^2+1)x + t
$$
over ${\bf C}(t)$ has a $I^*_{14}$ fiber at $t=\infty$.
(Note that the right-hand side is a cubic in $x$ whose discriminant
$4t^4 + 13 t^2 + 32$ has degree only $4$ in $t$, where a generic
K3 surface would have discriminant of degree $24$.)
$X$ is the unique such surface with a section, up to isomorphism.
The group of sections is trivial: the zero-section and the components of
the $\tilde D_{18}$ fiber already generate a lattice 
${\rm II}_{1,1} \oplus D_{18} \langle -1 \rangle$ of rank $20$ in
${\rm NS}(X)$, so the Mordell-Weil rank is zero (else the Picard number
would exceed $20$), and if there were
a $2$-torsion section then the Neron-Severi lattice would be
${\rm II}_{1,1} \oplus L \langle -1 \rangle$ for some
even unimodular lattice $L$ of rank $18$, which is impossible because
$18 \not\equiv 0 \bmod 8$.

[*added a bit later*: For the situation in positive characteristic see
[Schütt's paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509540),
which cites Shioda's note

> Shioda, T.: The elliptic K3 surfaces with a maximal singular fibre, 
>   *C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris, Ser. I*, **337** (2003), 461-466.

for the description of elliptic surfaces with a maximal singular fiber
in characteristic zero.]